# Is std::advance on an iterator of std::multiset done in constant time?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, multiset

I would like to know if calling std::advance on an iterator of std::multiset is done in constant time.

Comment: This question shows no sign of effort made to find the solution yourself. Just looking up cppreference would have sufficed.

Comment: Oh dear @Walter, I only wish I could show you my browsing history. cppreference doesn't say what kind of iterator can be obtained from std::multiset, Hence, I wasn't sure if std::advance can be done in constant time.
It would be great if didn't make assumptions on the nature of questions asked here. You know, most of us (like me) who use the internet aren't so well versed with C++ and are making an effort to learn. Getting a -1 will only discourage us further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`std::advance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance), we see that

> **Complexity**
>
> Linear. However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of RandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

As any template from the `std::*map` and `std::*set` family doesn't fulfill the `RandomAccessIterator` requirements, it's linear. From e.g. [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset):

> **Member types**
>
> [...]
>
> `iterator`               Constant BidirectionalIterator
> `const_iterator`     Constant BidirectionalIterator

Answer (score 5):

No, only random access iterators can advance in constant time. Otherwise, it's linear time on the distance.

See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

Comment: Could you provide a reference ?

Comment: Sure, I added the cpp reference link.

Comment: Well, at worst linear.  In theory one could write a multiset with log-speed advance iterators.  It would, however, cost some performance (not standards-breaking, just a constant factor) in other operations, and I am unaware of any std implementation that does this.

Comment: But how do I know if std::multiset returns a random access iterator? cppreference page only says that the "begin" method for multiset returns only iterator (doesn't mention which kind) - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/begin

Comment: As you can see in the members of multiset in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset, the iterators are bidirectional, not random.